# How to reset cn_internal_address parameter of Apache IoTDB cluster when there's already one confignode and datanode?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When deploying the cluster version of Apache IoTDB, the first node is successfully deployed, but the second node reports an error when deploying: `ERROR o.a.i.c.s.ConfigNodeCommandLine: 75 - Meet error when doing start checking iotdb.commons.exception.ConfigurationException: Parameter cn_internal_address can not be 192.168.4.58, please set to: 192.168.24.57. Because cn_internal_address can't be modified after first startup`. I understand that I cannot change this parameter `cn_internal_address`, so I want to know how can I reset this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have data stored under your second ConfigNode of Apache IoTDB? Delete the data under the second node and you should be able to reconfigure `cn_internal_address` parameter.